# Passing values from input fields in TextBox in ASP.NET webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, input, webforms, append

I have a problem with passing values from multiple input fields to a single asp Textbox. I have a field where I can enter a name and if I check the surname field it should allow me to enter the surname, related to the entered name. The problem is that I have an option to add many fields with name and I have to pass all the values in one Textbox. I am adding the fields with append function and I give different id for each field. How could I add the surname related to the name, for example if I have first row with only entered the name (Christian), and the second row added on click is with entered name (Christina) and checked surname entered (Grey). In my textbox I should have information like:

Name: Christian

Name: Christina Surname: Grey

Here is my code

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var num = 1;
        $("#but1").click(function () {
            num++;
            $("#name").append('<br><br>'+'<input type="text" id="name'+ num +'add"/>');
            $("#connectedSurname").append('<br>'+
                '<input type="checkbox" id="checkSurname"'+ num +'add"/>'+
                '<label for="checkSurname" id="labelCheck'+ num +'add">Surname</label>' +
                '<div id="connectedPhonesAdd">' +
                    '<input type="text" id="txtConSurname'+ num +'add"/>'+
                '</div>');
        });
    });
</script>


<div>
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>

<div id="name">
     <input type="text" id="name1add"/>
</div>
<input type="button" id="but1" value="Add">

</ContentTemplate>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkSurname1add"/>
    <label for="checkSurname" id="labelCheck1add">Surname</label>
    <div id="connectedSurname">
        <input type="text" id="txtConSurname1add"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="textPreview">
       <asp:TextBox ID="prevNameSurname" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
  </div>
 </div>
```

I have tried this in my .cs file, but it says that name1add does not exist in the current context

```
string val = name1add.Value;
prevNameSurname.Text = val;
```

I would be very grateful if anyone has a clue how to solve this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you considered using a [HiddenField](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hiddenfield?view=netframework-4.8)? If you need to use Javascript per your question, you could create a Javascript object and populate it with the custom fields. Then you use JSON.stringify() to get a string value of this object. Then you can set the value of the HiddenField to this JSON string. Finally, you can deserialise the string into an object in the codebehind (.cs) file on the button click event (or as needed)

Answer (score 0):

Your `name1add` and so on, are added with JavaScript when the page is loaded. The server side is not aware of these controls. You will have to manually manage them. Read their values on submit and send them back to the server and here you can use them and assign them to `prevNameSurname` control.